# Setting a string to an empty string in C

Tags: c

I want to write a Program in C that will accept a input .txt file, read from it and apply functions or display the text on stdout or write it to an out file.  For the sake of simplicity I wrote it to just display the words.

Complete code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <getopt.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv){

int c;

int output = 0;
FILE *infile;

while((c = getopt(argc, argv, "o:")) != -1){
    switch(c){

        case 'o':
            if(output){

                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            output = 1;

            break;
        case '?':
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        default:
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}

    for(; optind< argc; optind++) {
    infile = fopen(argv[optind], "r");


    size_t cpos = 0;
    char str[100];

    int ch;
    while((ch = fgetc(infile)) != EOF ) {
        if(ch == '\n' || ch == ' '){
            fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", str);
            str[0] = '\0';
            continue;
        } else{
            str[cpos++] = ch;
        }

    } 

    str[cpos] = 0;
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", str);

    fclose(infile);

    }
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }
```

My problem is part inside of while statement:

```
    for(; optind< argc; optind++) {
    infile = fopen(argv[optind], "r");

    size_t cpos = 0;
    char str[100];

    int ch;
    while((ch = fgetc(infile)) != EOF ) {
        if(ch == '\n' || ch == ' '){
            fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", str);
            str[0] = '\0';
            continue;
        } else{
            str[cpos++] = ch;
        }
    } 

    str[cpos] = 0;
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", str);

    fclose(infile);

    }
```

In `infile = fopen(argv[optind], "r")` I am saving a filename from `argv`. In `while` statement I am reading a chars from `infile` with `fgetc`   until `EOF`. I want to read every char until I hit a empty line or space. When I hit `'\n'` or `' '` I want to display that on `stderr`, reset that String to be empty and continue to read chars in next line. Else the `ch` will be placed on `str[cpos]` (`cpos` incrementents every loop). At the end  `str[cpos]` is set to `0` to mark a end of the string, the last `str` is printed and infile closed.

**Problem:**

if I input a .txt file (`./program -o out.txt input.txt`)

```
word1
word2
word3
```

All I get is

```
word1
```

I tried to set `str[0]= '\0'` as empty string but after that nothing is stored on `str`. How do I output all 3 words?

Comment: Please remove some empty lines before you post.

Comment: It's not the string resetting that is the problem. You need to do some basic debugging. Put printouts of variables inside loops to investigate what's going on.

Comment: you have potential UB printing out uninitialized `str` if the first character in the file is `'\n'` or `' '`. Also, that `continue;` statement is useless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not zero-terminated the string you build, and you didn't reset `cpos = 0;` for the next word.

The result is that you are continuing to write to `str[]` further along, beyond the `'\0'` that you terminated it with.

The loop should be like this:

```
while((ch = fgetc(infile)) != EOF ) {
    if(ch == '\n' || ch == ' '){
        str[cpos] = '\0';               // terminate this string
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", str);
        cpos = 0;                       // for next word
    } else{
        str[cpos++] = ch;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I see several potential problems:

1. You must reset `cpos` to zero when you encounter the whitespace.
2. Before the fprintf in the loop, you should be sure to nul-terminate the current str.
3. If the last character before EOF is `\n` or , you will output a blank line at the end.
4. I don't know your dataset, but I'd still be mindful about exceeding 99 characters of input, as you could overflow the buffer the first time you encounter a word with 100 or more characters.

Answer (score 1):

When you know your str array has all the chars from the word you must append your array with a terminator (zero byte) and reset cpos to 0 before collecting chars for a new word.

So imagine str is { 'w', 'o', 'r', 'd' }
and cpos is 4
you do str[cpos] = 0
and then str is { 'w', 'o', 'r', 'd', 0 }
and that's a correct null-terminated string

Empty string is { 0 }, that's correct

In any case don't forget to reset cpos to 0 because otherwise you'll be writing after the terminator.